# Changing an array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I created an array this way:

```
 arr = Array.new(4, Array.new(4, '*'))
```

When I try to change one element, for example the first element of the first array:

```
 arr[0][0] = 3
```

then every first element is changed.

```
 print arr
 [[3, "*", "*", "*"], [3, "*", "*", "*"], [3, "*", "*", "*"], [3, "*", "*", "*"]]
```

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do:

```
arr = Array.new(4) { Array.new(4, '*') }
```

Ruby array is in fact a set of pointers, which points onto some other objects n the memory. In your code all the pointers point to the same object created with `Array.new(4, '*')`. if, instead of the value, you will pass a block, this block will be executed for every element of the array, so each pointer will point to a new object in the memory.

In fact, the code above still have a similar issue with a string '*'.  You should use same method to fix it:

```
arr = Array.new(4) { Array.new(4) { '*' } }
```

Comment: thank you very much :) .. I should have thought about the pointers